# Creating many to many relation with AUTH_USER_MODEL in django via intermediary model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create the following models. There is a `ManyToMany` relation from `Entry` to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` via the `EntryLike` intermediate model.

```
class BaseType(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Title(BaseType):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class EntryLike(BaseType):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Entry(BaseType):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    liked_by_users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='EntryLike', through_fields=('entry', 'user'))
```

Running migrations on the above model scheme throws the error: `AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'meta'`.

Any help in resolving this error would be highly appreciated. Am new to Django & Python, but not to Web Development.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is almost certainly not a model instance.  It's probably a string that constrains the choices another model can make - settings would be a strange place to leave a model definition.

To do a MTM between the user model and your field above you need need to do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Entry(BaseType):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've added the **str** function so that it gives a more sensible return when you're manipulating it in admin/shell.

I'd also question whether you need the second set of fields (removed here), as you can use [select related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) between the Entry and EntryLike join table, without any duplication of the fields - you can probably go that way, it's just a bit unnecessary.

Lastly, I'd note that the way I'm using it above just uses the default User object that comes with Django - [you may wish to customise it.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) or extend the base class as you've done here with your own models' base class.

(All of this is predicated on AUTH_USER_MODEL not being a model instance - if it is, can you post the model definition from settings.py? )

Comment: Hi @Withnail, thanks for the detailed answer. `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not a model instance. I am importing `settings` as `from django.conf import settings`